# how to copy a index match formula to a whole column using Arrayformula in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Im trying to copy this formula

```
= INDEX(myrows, MATCH(B3 & "/Fashion Men",mycolumn,0) )
```

to the whole column.

WORKING OF THIS FORMULA:
(this formula  looks for value in given cell(B3 in this case) and concatenates with "/men" and searches it in range "mycolumn" and then after finding it, it gives that cell's row . so the final output is a single row present in range myrows)

I've tried the following but it only prints out a single row and doesn't goes down to read the values of B4 and so on.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( INDEX(myrows, MATCH(B3:B & "/Fashion Men",mycolumn,0) ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this instead:

`= ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B& "/Fashion Men",{mycolumn,myrows},{1,2,3,4},0)))`

You will need to update the {1,2,3,4} array to match the column numbers in the myrows range that you want to return

Comment: After wasting so many hours , this works wonders-Thanks a million Chris